# Constructing a divergent alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to construct the following?

> A sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $0 \le x_{n} \le 1/n $ where $\sum (-1)^n(x_{n}) $ diverges.

Comment: note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges mainly because grouping the terms by two you get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{(2n-1)(2n)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ is even, and let $x_n=0$ when $n$ is odd.